# Taking data from one text file and moving it to a new text file

Tags: java, file

I have a file that has data inside of it. In my main method I read in the file and closed the file. I call another method that created a new file inside of the same folder of the original file. So now I have two files, the original file and the file that is being made from the method that I call. I need another method that takes the data from the original file and writes it to the new file that is created. How do I do that?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class alice {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String filename = ("/Users/DAndre/Desktop/Alice/wonder1.txt");
        File textFile = new File(filename);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(textFile);
        in.close();
        newFile();
    }

    public static void newFile() {
        final Formatter x;
        try {
            x = new Formatter("/Users/DAndre/Desktop/Alice/new1.text");
            System.out.println("you created a new file");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Did not work");
        }
    }

    private static void newData() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Read a line from the file and use `printstream` to print it in another

Comment: Its like a story, so would it still work the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your requirement is to copy your original files content to new file. Then this may be a solution.

**Solution:**

*First, read to your original file using `BufferedReader` and pass your content to another method which creates new file using `PrintWriter`. and add your content to your new file.*

Example:

```
public class CopyFile {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String fileName = ("C:\\Users\\yubaraj\\Desktop\\wonder1.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    try {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        /**
         * Pass original file content as string to another method which
         * creates new file with same content.
         */
        newFile(stringBuilder.toString());
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }

  }

  public static void newFile(String fileContent) {
    try {
        String newFileLocation = "C:\\Users\\yubaraj\\Desktop\\new1.txt";
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(newFileLocation);
        writer.write(fileContent);//Writes original file content into new file
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("File Created");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have one more question, would I need to change a lot if I have more files that I want to write to that new file?

Comment: Yes I did. I have other files that I need to write to the new file. I was just asking if much was needed in order to do that.

Comment: Yes you need to change if you have multiple files

Comment: Alright, I will try it and if i can't fix it I will post another question. Thanks for your help.