# Reading .txt files in java

Tags: java, file

Reading a file in Java. I get the "FileNotFound" exception. 
Exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: something.txt (The file was not found)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at rmihello.ReadStringFromFileLineByLine.main(ReadStringFromFileLineByLine.java:13)
```

Even though my file is in my bin right next to my sourcecode:
I have also tried giving it the entire path to my file, e.g.

```
path = "C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/java/something.txt"
```

or

```
path = "cd 'C:/Users/Alexander/Desktop/java/something.txt'"
```

All of it fails
Here's my code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadStringFromFileLineByLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String path = "something.txt";
            File file = new File(path);
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
            }
            fileReader.close();
            System.out.println("Contents of file:");
            System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second snippet is a line of bash... it has nothing to do with Java. What error do you get ? Never ask for a fix without providing the error message

Comment: **Where** do you give the `path = ...` statements?  I can't see anywhere in your code that looks similar.

Comment: So, where do you use the `path` in the code?

Comment: He said he tried those paths, so I suppose he used it in the first line of the code.

Comment: You can take reference from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825383/taking-data-from-one-text-file-and-moving-it-to-a-new-text-file/26825577#26825577

Comment: Where is path brother ??

Comment: Sorry, path is added!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, your code should start like this:

```
 Path file = ; //Specify the path to your file
```

Take a look at [Reading, Writing, and Creating Files in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)  for more information

**Edit:**

Just edit your code like this it works fine for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
String path = "C://Something.txt"; // I put the file under the C: path in my example
try {
        File file = new File(path);
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
        }
        fileReader.close();
        System.out.println("Contents of file:");
        System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then just change the path to fit yours.

Comment: Sorry, this is added now!

Comment: It works fine for me, then if it doesn't work for him it's probably a problem of access permission to the file.

Answer (score 0):

A relative path adds to uncertainty where a file-not-found stems from.
As you tried alternatives, handle the error:

```
    File file = new File("C:/.../something.txt");
    try {
        ...
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       File full = file.getAbsoluteFile();
       File dir = file.getParentFile();
       while (dir != null && !dir.exists()) {
           dir = dir.getParentFile();
       }
       System.out.printf("File %s does not exist under %s%n",
               full.getPath(),
               dir == null ? "/" : dir.getPath());
    } catch (IOException e2) {
    }
```

Tips:

`StringBuilder` is faster, successor of StringBuffer.

New style (since Java 7):

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/...");
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
String contentText = new String(content); // Default encoding
```

Comment: I tried your catch phrase, It got me this:
File C:\Users\Alexander\Dropbox\java\workspace\rmihello\something.txt does not exist under /
My something.txt is in that rmihello folder

Comment: That is baffling (No rights on Users?), maybe try placing the file at another place.

Answer (score -1):

if you insert your text files into a folder named text_files for example, then you can access it using

> File f = new File("text_files/something.txt");

Comment: -1: If the current code is not working, then moving the files into a subdirectory and adding that to the front of the path will not work either.

Comment: why the current code not working? the problem i think is in the path for the text file.

and that does not lead to down vote i think

Comment: Well, we're not entirely sure (it isn't a great question).  But - your solution will work *if and only if* the existing code works.  The error is more likely due to the CWD being incorrect, or the user not having read permissions; neither of which your suggestion would solve.